# How to redirect people depending on form selection

Tags: php, javascript, html

with a simple html form, how can I redirect people depending on their selection?

```
<form id="contact-form" action="xxxxx" method="post">
<li>option1
<ul>
  <li><label>Red</label> <input type="radio" name="Option1" id="vsat" value="red"></li>
  <li><label>Blue</label> <input type="radio" name="Option1" id="blue" value="blue"></li>
  <li><label>White</label> <input type="radio" name="Option1" id="white" value="white"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>option2
<ul>
  <li><label>Big</label> <input type="radio" name="Option2" id="vsat" value="red"></li>
  <li><label>Small</label> <input type="radio" name="Option2" id="blue" value="blue"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Location
<ul>
  <li><label>Europe</label> <input type="radio" name="Option3" id="eur" value="eur">    </li>
<li><label>America</label> <input type="radio" name="Option3" id="ame" value="ame"></li>
</ul>
```

for example:

If the selection is: Red/Big/Europe go to www.somedomain.com/001

If the selection is: Blue/Big/Europe go to www.somedomain.com/006

If the selection is: blue/small/America go to www.somedomain.com/us/003

Thank you guys for any help!

Comment: Can you post some code you have tried?

Comment: It is not clear in what way you want to redirect. By PHP or JS ?

Comment: You should examine the POST-ed content on the PHP scripts that receives the submitted form data and use `header()` to redirect depending on what was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will use some kind of redirecting script, I'll use via header here.

```
<?php
   //this will NOT work, the browser received the HTML tag before the script or even a white space
   header( 'Location: http://www.linktoredirect.com/' ) ;
?>
```

Then you should make all options feels like one so you can use it in a switch or something like that.

```
<?php
$singleOption = $_GET['option1']."-".$_GET['option2']."-".$_GET['option3'];
//Now that you have one big option you can easily do:
switch($singleOption){
    case "red-big-europe": $sufix = '001'; break;
    case "blue-big-europe": $sufix = '002'; break;
    //And so on
    default: $sufix='404'; //some default value to redirect if it doesn't match anything
}
//With the switch you already have the sufix, so you only do:
header( 'Location: http://www.somedomain.com/$sufix' ) ;
?>
```

**//Edit**

Note that I haven't sanitized or validated the data. You should always keep your data clean and checked when they come from the user. 
Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onSubmit` handler to the form, examine the form values, and redirect to the desired page using Javascript. If you want it to work without Javascript, your PHP script can basically do the same thing by setting a HTTP `Location:` header to the URL you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery http://jquery.com/

I'd add a class to each input - ie .options , and add a data- attribute to each holding the url you want to direct to. And have a container to hold their selection ie:

```
<input type="hidden" name="location" id="location" />
```

then Something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.options').each(function() {
      $(this).click(function() {
         if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           var loc = $(this).attribute('data-location');
           $('#location').val(loc);
         }
       }
   }
});
```

then upon submit

```
 $('#formID').submit(function() {
    var loc = $('#location').val(); 
    window.location = loc;
 });
```

so that loops through all the radio buttons with the class 'options' and adds an event listener for when their clicked. So when someone clicks one it checks if it's been selected (as it may be clicked to de-select it) and if it is checked then it adds the url relevant to that choice (stored in data-location attr) to the #location hidden input. Then when the form is submitted it sends the user to that url , you'd want to add in things to handle an empty url etc.

Comment: Note that the OP did not specify how the redirections should be made.

Comment: Agreed, 'how can I redirect people depending on their selection' this is an option.

Comment: As a matter of fact it is not :D. He/She is not telling anywhere who should do the redirection PHP or JS. there are many approaches to do this based on requirements. So the questions should be flagged as not constructive.

Comment: Well OP has a JS suggestion, why don't you throw in a PHP alternative and then we've got all the bases covered

Comment: Well I could, but the question should be descriptive. Questions that are like:  `How to do that?` were not welcome in the SO community and should not be tolerated.